# Is it possible to write a recursive formula in excel to add products of array elements moving in opposite directions?

Tags: excel, recursion

I have a table of X Y and Z below:

[image: Table of x y and z]

As the formula in Z3 spells out, column Z contains the sum of the products of the last X and first Y, first X and last Y, and everything in between. I'm not sure how to put it into technical terms, but I guess I'm looking for the sum of products of two arrays moving in opposite directions? I am wondering what the recursive formula for this would be, and then if that recursive formula has any way of being implemented in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Note specifically addressing your question, but this may help.
Have you considered reversing one array and then doing a regular sumproduct or sum((xxx)*(yyy)), i.e., array product?

For example, you can reverse the array in column Y with the following:

In cell Z1, write this:

=INDEX($Y$1:$Y$3,ROWS($Y$1:$Y$3)-ROW()+1)

and then copy and paste down to row 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2021 or Excel for Microsoft 365, you can use:

```
Z1: =SUMPRODUCT(INDEX($X:$X,SEQUENCE(COUNT($X$1:X1))),INDEX($Y:$Y,SEQUENCE(COUNT($Y$1:Y1),,COUNT($Y$1:Y1),-1)))
```

and fill down as far as needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well to do recursion you would need access to the Lambda function - not sure if this generally available, it was only on the Beta channel of Excel 365 last time I looked. So you would create a formula like this:

```
=LAMBDA(x,y,ix,iy,IF(iy=0,0,XY(x,y,ix+1,iy-1)+INDEX(x,ix)*INDEX(y,iy)))
```

and add it to the Name Manager like this:

[image]

[image]

... although you would probably say that it is merely iteration dressed up as recursion ;-)

---

if you need to get the sum for the first one, two, three rows, use

```
=XY(X:X,Y:Y,1,ROW())
```